# how to calculate distance between any two elements in more than 10^8 data to Clustering them using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, hierarchical-clustering, bigdata

I have more than 10^8 records stored in elasticSearch. Now I want to clustering them by writing a hierarchical algorithm or using PIC based on spark MLlib.
However, I can't use some efficient algorithm like K-means because every record is stored in the form of

```
{mainID:[subId1,subId2,subId3,...]}
```

which obviously is not in euclidean space.
I need to calculate the distance of every pair of records which will take a very LONG time I guess (10^8 * 10^8). I know the cartesian product in spark to do such computing , but there will appear the duplicated ones like (mainID1,mainID2) and (mainID2,mainID1), which is not suitable to PIC.

Does anyone know a better way to cluster these records? Or any method to delete the duplicated ones in the result RDD of cartesian product?

Thanks A lot!

Comment: your question is not very clear, can you come up with simple example.

Comment: Actually, my final goal is to pick distinguish ones from the records set by a given search query, there are too many similar ones in the records set :(. So I want to clustering them firstly, and pick the ones from different cluster. Do you guys know a better way to pick distinguish ones in the beginning？

Comment: WHICH PART do you think is unclear? I'll make a example for that。 Thanks a lot!

Comment: the record form is like {'a' : [1,2,3,4,5]}, {'b':[1,2,3,6,8]},{'c':[3,5,7]}.     I want to cluster them based on the value ([1,2,3,4,5]). Noted that the number in list is just ID. So I have to calculate the distance between any two of them. Now I have more than 10^8 such kinds of records. I don't have a good idea to do this clustering. What I know is to use cartesian product, but this cost too much and will form the duplicated ones, which means the same distance I will calculate twice ((a,b)  and (b,a)). the PIC API only allows the same distance to appear once as input.

Comment: what is PIC? give complete example, what is input and what should be output after clustering, its hard to assume and answer.

Comment: The PIC is "power iteration clustering" algorithm in spark Machine Learning lib. It accepts [(a,b,dist(a,b)),(a,c,dist(a,c)),(b,c,dist(b,c))] as input. RDD is a basic storage type of spark.  the output should be like that the **a** and **b** are in the same cluster and **c**  is in another cluster. @amit_kumar

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't take the full Cartesian product:

```
select where a.MainID > b.MainID
```

This doesn't reduce the complexity, but it does save about 2x in generation time.

That said, consider your data "shape" and select the clustering algorithm accordingly.  K-means, HC, and PIC have three different applications.  You know K-means already, I'm sure.

PIC basically finds gaps in the distribution of distances.  It's great for well-defined sets (clear boundaries), even when those curl around each other or nest.  However, if you have a tendril of connecting points (like a dumbbell with a long, thin bar), PIC will not separate the obvious clusters.

HC is great for such sets, and is a good algorithm in general.  Most HC algorithms have an "understanding" of density, and tend to give clusterings that fit human cognition's interpretation.  However, HC tends to be slow.

---

I strongly suggest that you consider a "seeded" algorithm: pick a random subset of your points, perhaps

```
sqrt(size) * dim
```

points, where **size** is the quantity of points (10^8) and **dim** is the number of dimensions.  For instance, your example has 5 dimensions, so take 5*10^4 randomly selected points.  Run the first iterations on those alone, which will identify centroids (K-means), eigenvectors (PIC), or initial hierarchy (HC).  With those "seeded" values, you can now characterize each of the candidate clusters with 2-3 parameters.  Classifying the remaining 10^8 - 5*10^4 points against 3 parameters is a *lot* faster, being O(size) time instead of O(size^2).

Does that get you moving toward something useful?